# Facebook's onion site and Adblock Plus

Tags: onion-services, add-on

If you don't know already, you can use Adblock Plus scripts to modify how https://facebook.com/ works. And you can even do things to improve your privacy, such as disabling the "message seen" feature that people receive if you have viewed their messages in chat.

I'm wondering why I can't get these scripts to work with the [Facebook's onion](https://facebookcorewwwi.onion/) version as well, since they are apparently the same site.

Onion sites are special "hidden" sites that can only be accessed using the Tor Network. If you aren't familiar with Tor and hidden sites you may not be able to help much.

I go to the preferences of AdBlock plus in the Tor browser and

1. add new custom filter group
2. add new filter

These are the two filters I tried adding:

```
facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php$xmlhttprequest www.facebook.com/ajax/mercury/change_read_status.php
```

For the onion version, I just would replace `facebook.com` with `facebookcorewwwi.onion`

I got the link to block:  [How to disable "Seen by" in Facebook chat](http://www.popsugar.com/tech/How-Turn-Off-Seen-Facebook-35857900)

Nothing appears to operate differently on the onion Facebook and I don't see any hits on the filters in Adblock Plus.

This is another script that hides the "message seen" for Facebook, however I think it is for greasemonkey. If you think you can convert it to adblock somehow, take a look. https://github.com/ldiqual/facebook-read-status-disabler

To make this simple: Need to disable message seen using adblock plus on facebook's onion site (facebookcorewwwi.onion)